# How to use .onDrop in SwiftUI for .data UTType?

Tags: swiftui

**Goal:**
When you drag&drop an attachment from an outlook email to a Finder window, then this attachment is copied to that folder. I want to do the same when such an attachment is dropped onto my view.

**Current Situation:**
I have implemented drop functionality on a view in SwiftUI for files and folders. It works because I know that files/folders provide a URL which I can just use. But now, I want to support dropping for other objects, like attachments in Outlook eMails. The UTType here is `.data` or `.item`. But I do not understand how to load the data in the drop delegate.

Here's what I have working for files/folders:

```
providers.forEach { provider in
    if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: URL.self) {
        let _ = provider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { object, error in
            if let url = object {
                self.fileDropped(container: container, url: url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the provider also conforms to data (according to `hasItemsConforming`, I was able to write the following code.

```
providers.forEach { provider in
    provider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.data.identifier) { data, error in
        if data == nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            let target = self.container.volumeInfo.volumePath.appendingPathComponent("test")
            let file = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: target.path, contents: data as! Data)
            print(file)
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I'm getting a message "Cannot load representation of type public.data". Even if this would work, I'm not getting the file name and extension from this.

**Actual Question:**
How can I load drop items of type `.data` and also get their file name/extension? (keep in mind that I drag and drop an attachment from an Outlook eMail)

Comment: Is yours iOS or macOS? There are 2 ways of achieving drag and drop. `NSItemProvider` is the old way, `Transferable` is the new way. On macOS `Transferable` is not fully ready there are some bugs / limitations, hopefully gets fixed. On iOS `Transferable` works fine. What you are using is `NSItemProvider`. To answer your question, either way you have to conform to some protocols and provide your own way to serialise and de-serialise data. Decide which way you want to go first and then we can look at how you can learn things

Comment: I am working on a macOS-only app. I never heard or even read about Transferable anywhere. Thanks for the hint. I'll check that.

Comment: Just beware I did face issues with Transferable on the Mac like multi-selection on lists and drag and drop custom types to the finder. I have reported these bugs, hope they do get fixed

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I had a quick look and noticed that it is coming with macOS 13. I'm still on 12.6 for now. But apart from that (not really an issue with the usual adoption rates), I didn't find an example yet that shows how dropping works with items from outside the application. I'm talking about files/attachments/text coming from anywhere. The examples are in-app only. But I'll have a closer look at this and see what I can find.

Comment: Conceptually drag and drop outside the app is possible, it just doesn't seem to work on macOS (bug), same code works on iOS (to Files app). So create a small POC as a universal app and try it. Either way you need to upgrade to macOS 13 to try it.